# What is another way to say the word "Logicality"

Tags: word-choice

So my sentence is like this "He has showed both ***logicality*** and devotion when delivering his ideas"

What I mean is that he demonstrated a logic thinking/ being very logical. However logicality does not fully sound right, doesn't it ?

Comment: He demonstrated both *logic* and devotion.

Comment: "Sense" could work here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use ***[rationality](http://www.memidex.com/rationality+logicality)*** in your sentence:

> - the quality of being consistent with or based on logic.

- he has shown both rationality and devotion when delivering his speech.

***[Logicality](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/logical?q=logicality#logical__6)*** is a noun derived from the adjective  "logical"  and it is correct in your sentence,  but it formal and not commonly used ([Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=logicality%2Clogicalness%2Clogical&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clogicality%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clogicalness%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clogical%3B%2Cc0) ) and as a result may sound "unusual".

Another, even less common noun derived from logical is ***[logicalness](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/logicalness)***.